# How to access a computer behind two NAT routers?

Tags: ssh, router, nat

For technical reasons that I cannot change my computers at home are located behind two routers, only one of which (the one connecting my own network) I have control over.

Basically the setup is

Internet <-> R1 <-> private network 1 <-> R2 <-> private network 2

R2 is my router. The private networks are 192.168.10.0 and 192.168.1.0. The latter is mine.

Is there any way for me to reach my computer from the outside (i.e. the Internet)?

I am not adverse to renting a hosted server somewhere and run some sort of client on a computer inside my network to allow the hosted server to SSH to my home network.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of access do you need?  If you just need to remote in and do some work, I would recommend an application like [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.com) or [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com).  These allow you to remote in to your desktop and work as if you were sitting at your desk.  I believe the paid versions will also allow you transfer files between the remote computer and where you are connecting from, but it's been a while since I have investigated either application.  If you're talking about setting up a web or ftp server that people can access over the internet, that will get a bit more complex.

Comment: I mentioned SSH in the question and the tags. I cannot check the two products you refer to (my office's proxy won't let me) but my guess is that they solve the problem I don't have (how generally to control a remote computer) but not the problem I do have (how to do that when the target computer is in a private network).

Comment: Basically, I need an external connector and a local client for my computer at home so it can connect to the connector.

Comment: Hey! I checked out GoToMyPC on Wikipedia and it might be something that could work. Citrix appear to have an external connector. I'll have a look at the product. Thanks.

Comment: As long as your private network is connected to the internet, then either product will let you access them and control them.  However, many corporate environments (including where I work) do block access to the sites where you would go to connect to your remote computer because it is considered a security violation.  If you went the VPN/SSH route, they may spot and block that as well once you get it set up.

Comment: My private network is connected to the building's private network. The building's private network is connected to the Internet. There are no blocks for any sites. The only problem is the double-NAT.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask port forward from R1 or use some host in internet where you can build tunnel from home PC. There is actually possibilities to go through NAT but these need some more hacking. Look at [pwnat](http://samy.pl/pwnat/) for example

Comment: As I said, I only have control over one of the routers, the inner router. The tunnel is an option.

Comment: I understand that you don't have control but if you buy internet from someone running R1 maybe it is possible to get this port forwarding. If not then only option is tunneling

Comment: I don't think I can convince them to forward a port for me. I am only here for a year.